# my application keeps receiving "Unfortunately "My App" has stopped" after Running the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, webviewclient

After Implementing a WebView Client my application keep receiving "Unfortunately "My App" has stopped" after Running the app.
This is my maniefest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="amapps.com.uhss" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="UHS Sword And Shield"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="UHS Sword and Shield" >
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

As you can see I have already implemented the internet permissions

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(amapps.com.uhss.R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://uhsswordandshield.com/");
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

}
```

So could someone please tell me what is wrong with my manifest or main activity. 
My app was running before I implemented a WebView client into my app to handle opening links within my app. Thanks!

Comment: Why you doing findview twice paste error log and remove private Webview ....?

Comment: please mark the useful answer as an answer.

Comment: Oh ok sorry new to stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove line

```
private WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

after

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

Whenever you want to initialize something, **make sure you initialize them after `setContentView`** . **Your problem is that you initialized the `webView` twice**, the first one you initialized after `public class MainActivity extends Activity` hence you will get `nullpointerException` error.

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: Could you please explain why declaring a private method after my class caused the application to crash

Comment: Thanks! I am new to coding and just want to understand everything that I am doing. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

put this line in on create after setContentView

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(amapps.com.uhss.R.layout.activity_main);
     mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

create object of webview before onCreate() .

```
private WebView mWebView;
```

then  initialized webview object after setContentView.

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
private WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

Which is above the onCreate, you are trying to instantiate the web view even before the view is set using setContent view, so you'll receive null pointer exception. Please remove it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line into onCreateView() you are going wrong with findiview out of scope

```
private WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

you have to do it as following

```
private WebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(amapps.com.uhss.R.layout.activity_main);
 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
}
```